# Xcode took over my git installation, what happened?

Tags: xcode, git

I've been using git on my MacBook pro for years and have also had xcode installed but rarely if ever used it. Yesterday I accidentally opened xcode and immediately closed it. Then, git commands in my docker environment stopped working (git failed to detect that the directory was a git repo), so I went back to my regular environment and type git status, and saw the below message

```
You have not agreed to the Xcode license agreements. You must agree to both license agreements below in order to use Xcode.

Press the 'return' key to view the license agreements at '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/License.rtf'
```

If I run `which git` the output is `/usr/bin/git` - is this perhaps a version of git installed by xcode? What happened? How can I get my original git installation back? Thanks

Comment: How did you install git before?

Comment: Apple make some weird changes in their own version of Git for mysterious XCode purposes, and make XCode whack on Git sometimes so as to carry out their nefarious schemes. Oddly, installing XCode doesn't always install Git. There are some weird subtleties involved. It's all very annoying and I wish Apple wouldn't mess with open source software like this.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I was having the same problem after yesterday's update to Xcode. Running the following command in the Terminal fixed the problem.

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Source: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/666584

Comment: That did it! I can't imagine why xcode would just change the path like that

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, though I get this error when I run the command. I have verified that the folder exists though it only contains the man page for `whatis`. `xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/'`

Comment: The first time I ran git after the update, it triggered a background install of `command line developer tools` which after completed, I had to run `xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch` and now `git` works again... apple please stop breaking open source software.

Comment: Thanks..!! This resolves my problem after looking around for 3 hours.